# Can a cast from object to class ever fail when both are exactly the same?

Tags: c#

If I have the following code

```
object o = new Building(4, "something");
```

And I attempt the following

```
if(o.GetType() == typeof(Building))
    Building buildingCast = o as Building;
```

What could go wrong? I want to make sure that `buildingCast` can never be null from a problematic cast. Is there any way at all that cast could fail? Even something obscure?

The reason I ask is that I am cleaning up a test project and I am trying to weed out redundant code. There are checks against `buildingCast` possibly being null...

```
if(buildingCast == null)
    etc
```

...but we cannot reach the code in the if statement.

Comment: soo, you're trying to clean up sanity checks?

Comment: That will never be null if you are executing those 3 lines consecutively.

Comment: Always surround casts with a try-catch block

Comment: @ToonCasteele `as` will never throw an exception, try-catch will be redundant code.

Comment: Surrounding a cast of a reference type with try catch is pointless because if it fails it will return null and it wouldn't compile if it wasn't nullable.

Comment: `if(o.GetType == typeof(Building))` wouldn't compile (`GetType` is a method). Also, the `if(..)` is redundant. Either `buildingCast` will be a `Building` or `null` - no need to do the `if`

Comment: Yea sorry, I fixed my typo. The code above is out of context. The only reason I show the if(type check) is because I want to stop people from suggesting I leave the check there in case the types are not the same

Comment: @Kazuo The `null` check is effectively the type check, because `as` returns `null` if the types don't match. That means if you perform the type check as above, `if (o != null && o is Building)`, you can be sure that the types match in the following statement or block, so you could use a direct cast `(Building)o` instead, which won't return null then.

Comment: The question has already been answered, but I would recommend the author och any future readers to have a look at the `is` keyword. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't refactor for the sake of refactoring. If you have the following lines of code in a row

```
object o = new Building(4, "something");
Building c = o as Building;
```

Then by all means change it to

```
Building o = new Building(4, "something");
```

but if you have something like

```
public void SomeMethod(object o)
{
   //you absolutely need a sanity check here
   Building c = o as Building;
   if( c == null )
      {
         //throw exception perhaps
      }

   //this can also be rewritten as
   Building b = null;
   if(o != null && o is Building)
          b = (Building)o;
   else
       //throw exception or log..etc

}
```

If you attempt the following

```
if(o.GetType == typeof(Building))
    Building buildingCast = o as Building;
```

then you're creating a lot more redundant and in fact this would make the code a lot less readable, you'd have to do something like

```
Building buildingCast = null; //to be able to use outside the if
if(o.GetType() == typeof(Building))
        buildingCast = o as Building;

//you still end up with a null here if cast fails.
//this is the EXACT procedure of the 'as' operator anyway
//which does 
Building buildingCast = o is Building ? (Building)o : (Building)null;
```

..and of course if you are absolutely positive the types are the same by using a check beforehand then the cast will never fail.

Comment: So instead of checking the type, and then performing the cast, I should just cast and then handle the fact it is null afterward? The only reason the type check is in place is to ensure that the cast will not fail

Comment: with a little bit of observation you'll realize that your alternative of `GetType` is the exact same behavior of the `as` keyword.

Comment: This answer has useful information but here is my main question. In the last code part of your answer. Is there any way the cast can fail, if you KNOW the types are the same as has been proven by your if statement `if(o.GetType == typeof(Building))`

Comment: if you are absolutely positive the types are the same by using a check then the cast will NEVER fail.

Comment: Perfect. If you could add that to your answer I will be happy to accept

Comment: I will add it to my answer, however I don't mind much not being accepted, I mind a lot more if you understood and learned something new today. :)

Comment: I did indeed. But I like to accept the answer that clearly answers my question so that others can easily find the same answer.

Comment: That is not the definition of as though.. `as` never ever calls a casting operator on a user defined reference type (well, it never ever calls a casting operator). In most cases the result would be as you describe it, but from a technical point of view it is wrong.

Comment: i am not exactly sure what you mean by that? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx

Comment: @StanR. I did some testing, it seems that `as` does not cast. It only checks type. So I was actually right :)

Answer (score 2):

`Building buildingCast = o as Building;`

Usually, you see this kind of code when casting a class `o` without knowing whether it is the correct type (and able to cast to `Building`) or whether `o` is null.

Then, usually you see a null check afterword.

If you see this just above:

```
Building b  = new Building(4, "something");
object o = new Building(4, "something");
```

Then, the `as` is redundant.

However, if `o` is being passed in from some other part of the system, you can never be sure, hence the check.

Comment: I have edited my example to include that fact I do indeed check if the `o` object is of the correct type before casting

Comment: No reason do to that when you're using `as`. If it's null, it was either null to begin with, or wasn't the kind of object you tried to make it.

Answer (score 2):

If the actual type of `o` is assignable to `Building`, then this will work. If the actual type is not compatible, you will get `null` as result. So if `o` comes from anywhere else than the line above, you should leave the check there.

If you're 100% sure `o` is of type `Building`, then declare it as `Building`. If that's not possible, then you'll need to leave the checks in your code and cast it to one as early as possible. For example, assuming you instantiate it via reflection, and you know the type, then you should cast it immediately.

BTW, casting via `as` already performs the type check for you. If the type isn't applicable, it returns `null`.

Comment: Do note that `as` is not casting in OO-sense since no constructor is called. I just reacted on the "casting via `as`" semantics :)

Answer (score 1):

I read through the answers and it seems like no one really points out that `as` is not a cast, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx for more information.

Quoting the important section:

> Note that the as operator performs only reference conversions, nullable conversions, and boxing conversions. The as operator can't perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by using cast expressions.

Put in a bit descriptive (but not 100% correct) terms it means that `as` tries to change the type of the pointer and sees if it is possible to see what it is referencing as another type, but it will never try to call a casting operator, implicit or not. A huge difference from a low-level point of view.

And I'd also like to recommand you to have a look at `is` here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.80).aspx which basically is a `obj.GetType() == typeof(sometype)` on steriods (and you get rid of the issue of `obj` being `null`).

In general you use `as` when "converting" to an interface. `as` does not allow for coercion, so the object must be an implementation of the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

Those three lines of code should never fail.

However, there might be a case where a function is called with a parameter that isn't expected, due to a bug somewhere else in the program or someone calling a function incorrectly.

So, it's always good to have a check to make sure you got what you expected.